# There is no argument given in context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement the [repository pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) in `asp core`. Everything seems to work fine with a few adjustments,except adding it to the controller:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IDocumentRepository _context;

        public HomeController()
        { 
            _context = new DocumentRepository(new myContext());
        }
}
```

**DocumentRepository.cs**

```
public class DocumentRepository : IDocumentRepository, IDisposable
{

    private myContext context;

    public DocumentRepository(myContext context) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Document> GetDocuments()
    {
        return context.Document.ToList();
    }

    public Document GetDocumentByID(int id)
    {

        return context.Document.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

**IDocumentRepository.cs**

```
public interface IDocumentRepository : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<Document> GetDocuments();
    Document GetDocumentByID(int documentId);
    void InsertDocument(Document student);
    void DeleteDocument(int documentID);
    void UpdateDocument(Document document);
    void Save();
}
```

**The error**

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'options' of
>   'myContext.myContext(DbContextOptions)
>   dotnetcore..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Comment: What line is the error on (always give the exact location of the error when reporting on an error) and what is the code of `mycontext`? It looks like `mycontext` is requiring you to pass an object of type `DBContextOptions` to the constructor which you aren't but its hard to be sure from the code you have provided...

Comment: `myContext` requires an options parameter in the constructor, having said that, you should let the framework worry about that for you, ASP.Net Core relies heavily on dependency injection, and so should you.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the repository pattern isn't really needed with Entity Framework, [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/220126/145181) has a great explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply resolve `IDocumentRepository` from the DI container using constructor injection instead of manually instantiating it and it should work:

```
public class HomeController : Controller  {
    private IDocumentRepository _repository;

    public HomeController(IDocumentRepository repository) { 
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

For that, you'll need to ensure `IDocumentRepository` is correctly registered in `ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddScoped<IDocumentRepository, DocumentRepository>();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add it to the DI container in the first place.